# Customizing OOB List Forms and Technical Limitations

Tags: list-form, ootb

We are customizing OOB List forms [using `Javascript/jQuery`] for our work . This is basically a request form.

In a year, we can have 1000 requests coming in.

In case, over a period of time, the number of request items exceeds above 5000, the forms may not live up to expectations i.e. we won't be able to do any more action with the List forms.

What is the suggestion for development of these forms?

Please note **Server side/App Development/InfoPath** are all ruled out due to guidelines. Please provide your inputs .

Comment: Welcome! Please also include (and/or tag) version of Sharepoint and whether on-prem/online when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The list form and the list view thresh hold are 2 different concerns. On the customized form, the JavaScript should perform the same every time, unless there are things it is trying to do based on information from the very list it lives in.

The list view thresh hold is a separate issue entirely from a customized form. Think about what column data is important. Index those fields, create filtered views so no more than 5000 items are returned. Put information rights policies on the list to delete items after a set time if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can have millions of form in the list, their is no issue with the number of items in list. Actual Problem arise with [List View ThresHold](https://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/sharepoint-2010-list-view-threshold-explained/), which limit is 5000. 
That mean, in a give view if more than 5000 items return then it will throw the error.

But their are workaround available, i.e use the index column and filter the views on the basis of index column. Check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx

Note: You did not mentioned the SharePoint version...But In MSFT ignite conference they announces in the new version of SharePoint this limitation will be increased. So almost a year later, i think you will be fine if you are on SharePoint online.